# GetAdaptersInfo not picking up all adapters

Tags: c, windows, winapi, ip-address

I am using GetAdaptersInfo API to list all the adapters on the system.  However, it does not seem to be picking up all of them.  IPCONFIG lists more adapters than GetAdaptersInfo is returning.

This is the stripped down code I am using:

```
#define MAX_ADAPTERS    64
PIP_ADAPTER_INFO pAdapterInfo;
DWORD dwRetVal;
ULONG ulOutBufLen = sizeof (IP_ADAPTER_INFO)*MAX_ADAPTERS;
pAdapterInfo = (PVOID) malloc(ulOutBufLen);
if (pAdapterInfo) 
{
    dwRetVal = GetAdaptersInfo(pAdapterInfo, &ulOutBufLen);
    if (dwRetVal == 0)
    {
        // enumerate adapters
    }
}
```

Is GetAdaptersInfo the correct API to enumerate all the adapters?

Comment: Added the stripped down code

Comment: You mean the return value from the API?  It is zero (Success).

Comment: I ended up using GetIpAddrTable instead. That does return all the adapter IP addresses.

Comment: @NeilWeicher: `GetAdaptersInfo()` has been deprecated since XP, use `GetAdaptersAddresses()` instead, which supports a lot more than `GetAdaptersInfo()` does